# Emulating a LEFT JOIN in Spring Entity

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

In effect, what I am trying to do is this...

```
SELECT a.*, b.description, c.description FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON b.code = a.b_code
LEFT JOIN c ON c.code = a.c_code
```

I would like to map this entirely using Spring/JPA framework. I've played around with @SecondaryTable only to find out that it will not work in thie case, and I've been getting a number of errors while trying to map it using @OneToOne or @JoinColumn. Here are my current entity classes...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class a {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "b_code")
    private String bCode;

    //I'd like to have b.description here

    @Column(name = "c_code")
    private String cCode;

    //I'd like to have c.description here
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class b {
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class c {
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@JoinColumn` with `referencedColumnName` as shown below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class a {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "b_code")
    private String bCode;

    //I'd like to have b.description here

    @Column(name = "c_code")
    private String cCode;

    //I'd like to have c.description here
    
    @OneToOne // this should be based on your joining
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_code", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    B b;
    
    @OneToOne// this should be based on your joining
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_code", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    C c;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "c")
public class C {
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```